# How can I use time series database and visualization frameworks to render growing data with ancient timestamps?

Tags: time-series, grafana, influxdb, timeserieschart, influxdb-2

I am gathering time series data from the game "Patrician 3" (inventory of each town and trading office), which takes place in the middle ages (1300+). Since transforming time series data into graphs is a solved problem, I'd like to use an established solution instead of building my own.

I have tried InfluxDB + Grafana, but have encountered two issues:

- The minimum value for InfluxDB timestamps is `1677-09-21T00:12:43.145224194Z` , more than 300 years too late.
- Grafana has very nice relative time ranges, but they all revolve around (the real) `now`, whereas my `now` is the timestamp of the latest data point (which is some day and time in the middle ages).

I have mitigated the first issue by adding a few hundred years to my timestamps, but I have found no way to manipulate the Grafana time range from dashboard variables. I found one person with a [similar problem in the grafana community forum](https://community.grafana.com/t/manipulate-the-relative-time-range-in-grafana-dashboard-according-to-custom-variables/67245), but they got no response. [Feature requests going into that direction](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/discussions/38138) exist, but see no progress. The [other direction appears to work](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-get-the-time-range-selected-on-the-dashboard-into-a-variable/2868), though.

Are there any time series database and visualization frameworks that support this use case? Did I miss any solutions for this problem with InfluxDB+Grafana?

Comment: I'm not familiar with flux, so sorry if my idea is utter nonsense, but couldn't you find max present date, and shift every date so said max date becomes now?

Comment: that's a nice workaround in general, but then the users have a harder time mapping displayed timestamps to correct timestamps

Comment: Oh, right. Then I personally don't see any solution within your current stack. Oh. and by the way "Are there any time series database and visualization frameworks that support this use case?" can be seen as search for tool recommendations (which are forbidden on SO). Since there is oncoming mods/curators strike in near hours, you might get away with it, but I'd recommend rewording your question, so that it is more in search of solution, rather then recommendations.

Comment: You might try CnosDB (https://docs.cnosdb.com) which is another open source TSDB as its timestamp's data type is i64 (written as an i64 representing milliseconds since the Unix Epoch). That is, it can support your case.